# Option to give passphrase via web interface

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, javascript

I am trying to run the sample web3.js code from here

https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/blob/master/example/event_inc.html

I am running the geth node on testnet. However, when I try to create the contract, I am prompted for my account passphrase in the geth console.

Is there any option to provide the passphrase via the web interface to authenticate the user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can unlock accounts with

`web3.personal.unlockAccount("0x1234...","password")`